# Is it a form of discrimination to make someone ask numerous questions?

Tags: discussion, bible

Is it a form of discrimination to make someone ask numerous questions before they can reply to a question they are most able to reply to? Yes.

Is it a form of duplicity to make someone hungry to join only then to blockade them with a ridiculous "reputation points" embargo, when such an embargo is not made explicit? Yes.

Please cancel my registration here.

Comment: Protected questions clearly say "Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site" - I don't see how you could think that it's not explicit.

Comment: Maybe if you knew how much spam this site has to deal with then maybe you would understand.

Comment: The moderators can't delete your account for you.  You need to request it [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/contact)

Comment: You only need ten points to answer protected questions. That's two up votes on a question and only one on an answer. "Numerous" is not the word I'd use; it's a pretty low bar, and only on questions that have a history of attracting non constructive attention.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it a form of discrimination to make someone ask numerous questions before they can reply to a question they are most able to reply to? Yes.

Yes, of course it's discrimination. And it's completely appropriate.

It discriminates against people with little knowledge of our system, who are more likely to create low-quality posts, which ultimately end up being deleted.

This sort of discrimination is entirely appropriate here, and everywhere.